# $a_n\leq b_n$ for almost all $n\in\mathbb{N}\implies \limsup_n a_n\leq\limsup_n b_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be two sequences such that $a_n\le b_n$ for almost all $n$. Does this imply that 
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n\le\limsup_{n\to\infty}b_n?
$$

To my opinion, yes! Since set
$$
a:=\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n,~~~~~b:=\limsup_{n\to\infty}b_n
$$
and suppose that $a>b$. Then, choosing a neighborhood around $a$ that does not contain $b$, there are infinitely many $a_n$ in this neighborhood, i.e. almost all $a_n$ are bigger than $b$ and almost all $a_n>b_n$.

But I do not know if this makes sense.

**Edit**

Maybe it would be better to choose $\varepsilon:=\lvert a-b\rvert/3$ and to consider $B_{\varepsilon}(a)$ and $B_{\varepsilon}(b)$, the open balls around a and b with radius $\varepsilon$. Then there are infinitely many $a_n$ in $B_{\varepsilon}(a)$ and infinitely many $b_n$ in $B_{\varepsilon}(b)$, hence $a_n>b_n$ for almost all n.

Comment: The claim is correct but the reasoning is not stringent in my opinion. Note that $\limsup_n (1 +\frac{1}{n}) = 1$ despite the fact that infinitely many sequence elements are bigger than $1$. You need to remark that only finitely many $b_n$ can be elements of the neighbourhood of $a$ you've chosen. For this it is not sufficient that $b$ is not in that neighbourhood, but you need that a whole neighbourhood of $b$ does not meet that of $a$ (which, of course, can be acchieved).

Comment: (and unlike in Sonners answer I assume that almost all means all but finitely many)

Comment: comment to the edit: this looks better now, but the formulation still is not to the point. you need to remark that all but finitely many $b_n$ are in $B_\varepsilon(b)$. This does not follow if you know that infinitely many $b_n$ are in that set.

Comment: "and infinitely many $b_n$ in $B_{\varepsilon}(b)$": This is true, but it is not relevant. What you need instead is "and only finitely many $b_n$ in $B_{\varepsilon}(a)$."

Comment: @Thomas: It is not necessarily true that all but finitely many $b_n$ are in $B_\varepsilon(b)$. An infinite number of the $b_n$ can be _less_ than $b - \varepsilon$.

Comment: I wonder about the following. The limit superiors, i.e. a and b, are the largest limit points of $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$, respectively. What, if both sequences have another limit point, say, $a'$ and $b'$ with $a'\leq b'$. Then, if $a_n\leq b_n$ for almost all $n$. and $a>b$, we can still have that almost all $a_n\leq b_n$, or?

Comment: @TonyK right you are.

Comment: Moreover, $\limsup_n a_n\le \liminf_n b_n$.

Comment: @zhoraster: That's wrong, I'm afraid. Take for example $a_n = b_n = (-1)^n$.

Comment: @TonyK, oops, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "almost all" you mean "an infinite number" (if instead you mean "all but a finite number" then the result is truly obvious).

In this case the thesis is false. Take $a_n=(-1)^n$ and $b_n=0$. Then $a_n<b_n$ infinitely often but $\limsup a_n=1>0=\limsup b_n$.

The problem is that in fact in this situation, "almost always" $a_n>b_n$ and "almost always" $a_n<b_n$, so that your language is not really justified. To formalize it, we use ultrafilters.

Comment: No, "almost all" does in fact mean "all but a finite number". The result is, as you say, fairly obvious.